# About "Do not use custom signals to distribute property change information." in the AllJoyn Interface Design Guidelines v1.1

Tags: alljoyn

AllJoyn `"Interface Design Guidelines v1.1"` mentioned that`"Do not use custom signals to distribute property change information."`

### So,If I defined an interface as following:

Interface Name: org.example.Fan
Properties:
IsOpened
...
Methods:
...

And `Set 'org.freedesktop.DBus.Property.EmitsChangedSignal' annotation value to true.`

Then, I must not define a `'IsOpenedChanged'` signal for this `'IsOpened' property`.
I should use `'org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.PropertiesChanged'` signal to inform interested observers.

Am I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you don't need to define a new signal named `IsOpenedChanged`. The property changed signal is handled behind the scene by the AJ library. You should only use

- the PropertyChangedEmitter (Java) https://allseenalliance.org/docs/api/java/org/alljoyn/bus/PropertyChangedEmitter.html or
- EmitPropChanged (C++) on a bus Object https://allseenalliance.org/docs/api/cpp/classajn_1_1_bus_object.html#a840c67af2c4e9a07566b71491c67cbc5

Comment: Thanks for your response.
But my platform is an AllJoyn thin core device, I can't find the similar implementions in the AllJoyn offical website.
My another question is : 
Could I define a ‘IsOpenedChanged’ custom signal for this property when I set 'org.freedesktop.DBus.Property.EmitsChangedSignal' annotation value to false? 
Does this conform to the Interface Design Guideline?

Comment: Following the ID Guideline, they suggest: _Don't Reinvent Updating Properties with Signals_

Comment: Hi Lino, Thanks for your response.

Comment: Allseen-irb members have same comments as yours. 
https://lists.allseenalliance.org/pipermail/allseen-irb/2016-May/000784.html